# How to get the integer part of the solution of system of linear equation using numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, type-conversion, output

```
import numpy as np

# Linear Equations
# x+3y-2z=5
# 3x+5y+6z=7
# 2x+4y+3z=8

A = np.array([[1,3,-2], [3,5,6], [2,4,3]])
B = np.array([[5,7,8]])
B = B.T
ans = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
print(ans)
```

I wanted to solve these system of liner equation and print the values of x y and z using Gaussian Elimination
The output is an array as expected.

```
OUTPUT:    
[  [-15.]     
 [  8.]       
 [  2.]  ]
```

I just want it as integer like -15, 8, 2 so I can then print out values `x=-15, y=8, z=2`
if I try converting it to `int(ans[0])`(or even to a list) but its giving their floor value that is -14, 7, 1 respectively.
Please tell how can I get the value -15, 8, 2 as integers.

PS: I tried with string and got the desired value but it is tedious to do and it would be great to get integers directly for further operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the result in `ans` are floats, the result is not actually `[-15, 8, 2]` even though that is what is displayed. Hence, when using `ans[0][0]` you will get something like: `-14.999999999999993`.

Now, since it's not a whole number, when using `int()` python will automatically round down. This is why you get -14 instead.

One possible solution would be to use [`np.rint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rint.html) which will round elements in an numpy array to the nearest integer. Below, the list is also flattened to 1-dimension:

```
ans = np.rint(ans).flatten()
```

Now, accessing the elements as ints can be done with `ans[0]`, `ans[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually solve your problem with a simple well-known function such as `round()`:

```
import numpy as np

# Linear Equations
#  x + 3y - 2z = 5
# 3x + 5y + 6z = 7
# 2x + 4y + 3z = 8

# Define the matrix system
A = np.array([[1,3,-2], [3,5,6], [2,4,3]])
B = np.array([[5,7,8]])
B = B.T

# Solve the system
ans = np.linalg.solve(A, B)

# OPTION 1: Nearest integers, but still float
ans1 = ans.round()

# OPTION 2: Nearest integers
ans2 = ans.round().astype(int)
```

As Shaido said before, you can add `.flatten()` for a simpler access to answer values.

Hope this was useful ;)

Comment: Yes it is good to know about various techniques, Thank You, it also worked!